Measurement to compare the width of the autocorrelation peak
I would like to know if there is a metric to compare the autocorrelation peak width of one signal with the peak width of another signal. Additionally, what does it mean to have a broad autocorrelation peak versus a narrow peak?

The autocorrelation is the inverse Fourier Transform of the Power Spectrum Density and all Fourier Transform relationships apply. Some course rules of thumb

If the peak is narrow and smooth it's probably a broadband signal with a fairly smooth spectrum.
If the peak is wide and smooth the signal has probably a "low pass" character
If the peak is wide and oscillating or quasi periodic, it's a narrow band signal

None of these is "precise" and there are plenty of exceptions.

The width of the autocorrelation peak is an indication of independence from sample to sample, and specifically how much "memory" is in each sample compared to prior samples. "White Noise", which has a constant power spectral density in frequency (hence the term "white"), has an autocorrelation function that is an impulse in time. This is because every sample is completely independent of every other sample, so when computing the autocorrelation function, a strong correlation results only when the signal is completely aligned with itself. If we were to low pass filter a white noise signal, then due to the filter itself which has an impulse response extending over time, every sample is a weighted sum of prior samples based on that impulse response (every sample has memory of prior samples). The extent of this memory causes the autocorrelation function to widen, given we will now have a correlation result that persists for some amount of delay between the signal and a delayed copy of itself.
